# Why does a jcrontab error appear in weblogic whenever I try to load my application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, cron

I get an Error 403 forbidden whenever I try to load my app in weblogic. The weblogic console loads fine. In the weblogic log all I see is:

```
<May 7, 2015 4:29:16 PM EDT> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as
no data read from it during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs>
<May 7, 2015 4:29:16 PM EDT> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as
no data read from it during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs>
<May 7, 2015 4:29:16 PM EDT> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as
no data read from it during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs>
<May 7, 2015 4:29:16 PM EDT> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as
no data read from it during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs>
<May 7, 2015 4:29:16 PM EDT> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as
no data read from it during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs>
```

Every so often I see this as well but I'm not sure if it's related:

```
<May 7, 2015 4:35:54 PM EDT> <Warning> <netuix> <BEA-423420> <Redirect is execut
ed in begin or refresh action. Redirect url is /console/console.portal?_nfpb=tru
e&_pageLabel=AppDeploymentsControlPage.>
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jcrontab.data.CrontabEntryDAO.findAll(CrontabEntryDAO.java:83)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.readCrontab(Cron.java:241)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.generateTasks(Cron.java:256)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.run(Cron.java:184)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jcrontab.data.CrontabEntryDAO.findAll(CrontabEntryDAO.java:77)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.readCrontab(Cron.java:241)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.generateEvents(Cron.java:256)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.run(Cron.java:184)
```

I've never heard of jcrontab before, can anyone shed some light on this? My app worked fine but when I deployed today, it started doing this. I don't think I've made any changes, none that I can remember.

On startup, this is displayed, again I'm not sure if it's related:

```
<May 7, 2015 4:42:17 PM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server stat
e changed to STARTING>
Working?...java.io.FileNotFoundException: \opt\apps\java\webapps\distNetwork\con
fig\distNetwork_jcrontab.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at org.jcrontab.web.loadCrontabServlet.createPropertiesStream(loadCronta
bServlet.java:64)
        at org.jcrontab.web.loadCrontabServlet.process(loadCrontabServlet.java:8
6)
        at org.jcrontab.web.loadCrontabServlet.init(loadCrontabServlet.java:55)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(St
ubSecurityHelper.java:283)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(Authenticate
dSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecuri
tyHelper.java:64)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubL
ifecycleHelper.java:58)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHel
per.java:48)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubI
mpl.java:521)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppS
ervletContext.java:1893)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(
WebAppServletContext.java:1870)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAp
pServletContext.java:1790)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletCon
text.java:2999)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.jav
a:1371)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:468)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:204)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineD
river.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStat
eDriver.java:60)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedMod
uleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(Module
ListenerInvoker.java:117)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:204)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineD
river.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStat
eDriver.java:60)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartMod
ulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.ja
va:635)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineD
river.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.
java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.ja
va:16)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(Deploym
entStateChecker.java:162)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(Ap
pContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicD
eployment.java:184)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromSer
verLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(De
ploymentAdapter.java:51)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(Deploy
mentAdapter.java:196)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(App
Transition.java:30)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionA
pps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(Co
nfiguredDeployments.java:169)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(Conf
iguredDeployments.java:123)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(De
ploymentServerService.java:173)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(Dep
loymentServerService.java:89)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
OK
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at org.jcrontab.data.DataFactory.<init>(DataFactory.java:52)
        at org.jcrontab.data.DataFactory.getInstance(DataFactory.java:69)
        at org.jcrontab.data.CrontabEntryDAO.<init>(CrontabEntryDAO.java:55)
        at org.jcrontab.data.CrontabEntryDAO.getInstance(CrontabEntryDAO.java:67
)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.readCrontab(Cron.java:241)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.generateEvents(Cron.java:256)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.run(Cron.java:151)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jcrontab.data.CrontabEntryDAO.findAll(CrontabEntryDAO.java:77)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.readCrontab(Cron.java:241)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.generateEvents(Cron.java:256)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.run(Cron.java:151)
Working?...java.io.FileNotFoundException: \opt\apps\java\webapps\it0016\jcrontab
.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at org.jcrontab.web.loadCrontabServlet.createPropertiesStream(loadCronta
bServlet.java:64)
        at org.jcrontab.web.loadCrontabServlet.process(loadCrontabServlet.java:8
6)
        at org.jcrontab.web.loadCrontabServlet.init(loadCrontabServlet.java:55)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(St
ubSecurityHelper.java:283)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(Authenticate
dSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecuri
tyHelper.java:64)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubL
ifecycleHelper.java:58)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHel
per.java:48)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubI
mpl.java:521)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppS
ervletContext.java:1893)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(
WebAppServletContext.java:1870)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAp
pServletContext.java:1790)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletCon
text.java:2999)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.jav
a:1371)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:468)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:204)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineD
river.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStat
eDriver.java:60)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedMod
uleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(Module
ListenerInvoker.java:117)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:204)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineD
river.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStat
eDriver.java:60)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartMod
ulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.ja
va:635)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineD
river.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.
java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.ja
va:16)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(Deploym
entStateChecker.java:162)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(Ap
pContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicD
eployment.java:184)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromSer
verLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(De
ploymentAdapter.java:51)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(Deploy
mentAdapter.java:196)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(App
Transition.java:30)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionA
pps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(Co
nfiguredDeployments.java:169)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(Conf
iguredDeployments.java:123)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(De
ploymentServerService.java:173)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(Dep
loymentServerService.java:89)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
OK
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at org.jcrontab.data.DataFactory.<init>(DataFactory.java:51)
        at org.jcrontab.data.DataFactory.getInstance(DataFactory.java:68)
        at org.jcrontab.data.CrontabEntryDAO.<init>(CrontabEntryDAO.java:54)
        at org.jcrontab.data.CrontabEntryDAO.getInstance(CrontabEntryDAO.java:66
)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.readCrontab(Cron.java:241)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.generateTasks(Cron.java:256)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.run(Cron.java:151)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jcrontab.data.CrontabEntryDAO.findAll(CrontabEntryDAO.java:83)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.readCrontab(Cron.java:241)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.generateTasks(Cron.java:256)
        at org.jcrontab.Cron.run(Cron.java:151)
<May 7, 2015 4:42:21 PM EDT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The Server
has established connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service successfully
.>
<May 7, 2015 4:42:21 PM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server stat
e changed to ADMIN>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was unrelated to crontab. I got rid of the crontab errors by disabling some other app ear files that relied on it. As for not displaying my app, I was running the wrong build script... I'm not sure if that will help someone who runs into this error, but maybe it will get you started in the right direction.